# Many to Many Efficient Routing using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, routing

I am given a large set of random locations and a set of set office location. I would like to map the random locations to the set of office locations based on travel time and efficiency of the route and mapping.

So basically, given a time or distance that each office can cover(which can change base on the office), is there anyway to create a most efficient routing?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is what the [ArcGIS Network Analyst extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/networkanalyst) was designed for.  An [extensive tutorial](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00470000005r000000) exists which should get you started.

A free training seminar is also available from ESRI:

[Training Seminar](https://training.esri.com/gateway/index.cfm?fa=catalog.webCourseDetail&courseID=1955)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Network Analyst extension, performing a [Closest Facility](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Make_Closest_Facility_Layer/004800000008000000/) will identify which destinations are most efficiently served by each office. You'll want to load the offices as the facilities in the Network Analyst toolbar. The analysis will be based on the cost (likely speed) that you assign to the roads in your network.

You can also construct an [Origin-Desination (OD) Cost Matrix](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help../index.html#/OD_cost_matrix_analysis/00470000004r000000/), which will tell you the amount of time and distance it takes to get from each office to each of the destinations. Here, you'll want to load your offices as the origins and the set of locations you create as the destinations. Again, this will be based on the costs that you assign to the different parts of your network.

If you have a set of known destinations, Closest Facility would be more helpful than [Service Areas](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//004700000048000000). A service area analysis outputs a set of polygons that shows how far from an office a person can travel on the network in a given amount of time(s). This would be useful if you don't have a set of known destinations. Using this output, you could still derive the areas most efficiently served by each office.

Answer (score 0):

Our RW Net 4 library (http://www.routeware.dk) can also be used with Python/ArcGIS to do such calculations. Much cheaper than Network Analyst.